# Копирование из одного ArrayList в другой

Tags: java

Привет,подскажите,никак не могу понять.Вот есть у нас массив

```
 ArrayList<String>
```

В массиве 76 элементов,далее есть число int sc = 0;
Так вот если переменная равна 0 добавить во второй массив первые 30 элементов из первого массива ,если 1,то еще 30,и так пока массив не кончится.Пробовал сделать через System.arraycopy,что-то не получилось(.Что подскажите?

Comment: А через .subList не пробовали? Так же есть аналогичный метод Collections.copy(List<?> dst, List<?> src)

Comment: Если бы вы кинули пару примеров,был бы очень признателен)

Comment: А просто самому цикл из нескольких строк написать не быстрее, чем искать готовое обобщенное решение?

Comment: @avp, пробовал нифига,если покажите примерчик буду рад)

Comment: @ваняя, Java под рукой нет, но что-то в таком роде:

    int n = sc*30 + 30, m = srcList.size();
    if (n > m)
      n = m;
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      res[i] = srcList[i];
    return res;

Comment: В java так будет,только так писать нельзя res[i] = sizel[i]; это же стринг



  int n = 1 * 30 + 30, m = sizel.size();
  if (n > m) {
   n = m;
  }
  ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   res[i] = sizel[i];
  }

Comment: @ваняя, почему нельзя?

В обоих ArrayList будут ссылки на одни и те же объекты типа String. 

Что Вас тут не устраивает?

Если зачем-то нужны копии, то вместо res[i] = src[i] можно написать

    res[i] = new String(src[i]);

Кстати, если в res вам нужна "очередная" тридцатка, то 

    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>(n - sc*30);
    for (int i = sc*30; i < n; i++)
       ....

Comment: Да так лучше)
@Rams666 , @avp , спасибо все заработало,пойду лучше java учить ,чтобы таких вопросов не было

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот пример с использованием subList:

```
    List<String> srcList = new ArrayList<String>();
    srcList.add("1");
    srcList.add("2");
    srcList.add("3");
    srcList.add("4");
    srcList.add("5");
    srcList.add("6");

    List<String> dstList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (true) {
        dstList.addAll(srcList.subList(0, 3));
    }
    System.out.println(dstList.toString());

    if (true) {
        dstList.addAll(srcList.subList(3, 6));
    }
    System.out.println(dstList.toString());
```

Comment: Кстати,небольшая проблема,я вот копирую массив просто так,но у меня размер массива (откуда я копирую)75,а копирую я по 30 элементов(две переменные начала копирования и конца),Что посоветуете For использовать,@Rams666 ,что думаете по этому поводу,пример :
   for(int i = startcopy;i<endcopy;i++){
   вот тут если копировать массив ,то будет хрень
       dstList.addAll(srcList.subList(startcopy, i));
       Не понимаю почему(
       Но если просто вывести i,то норм 30 чисел выводятся,а если                     заполнять с помощью i,то фиг(
     }

Comment: Вы что хотите, добавить в конец нового массива оставшиеся элементы?

Comment: Да,просто сейчас вылетает ошибка я же по тридцать добавляю(всего 75),пятнадцать не добавляется(

Comment: Вам нужно добавить проверку: если в массиве осталось 30 элементов, тогда добавить 30, если же нет - то добавить оставшиеся элементы.

Comment: Вот,пример бы не помешал,пожалуйста)

Comment: Ваш код "в студию" - на его примере и покажу! Вариантов на самом деле много...

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению,весь код предоставить не могу, но участки дам:

```
 ArrayList<String> sizel = new ArrayList<String>();//исходный элемент содержит не определенное количество элементов(сейчас 75)
     int pageint = 0;
            pageint = sc.nextInt();

                ArrayList<String> sizetri = new ArrayList<String>();

                int endlist = pageint * 30;
                int startlist = endlist - 30;

                sizetri.addAll(siz.subList(startlist, endlist));
```

**UPD**
или так :

```
for (int i = startlist; i < endlist; i++){
   sizetri.addAll(siz.subList(startlist, i));
}
```

Comment: И все?) больше ничего не надо?

Comment: Лучше сделать немного по-другому:

    int startlist = (pageint-1) * 30;
    int endlist = (sizel.size() >= (startlist+30)) ? (startlist+30) : sizel.size();

Comment: @Rams666 , @avp , спасибо все заработало,пойду лучше java учить ,чтобы таких вопросов не было